# How to set up Artifactory behind a reverse proxy with a sub-context

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to set up Artifactory (CPP-CE) behind NGINX reverse proxy, with a custom context. I.e. all Artifactory URLs should be behind some top-level context (e.g. `/conan`). So the UI URL is supposed to be at `https://server.com/conan/ui`, and repository endpoints behind `https://server.com/conan/artifactory`.

I can't seem to find a way of telling Artifactory that. The documentation is honestly not particularly helpful.

I've tried setting `X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url` to `$http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/conan/artifactory` or `$http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/conan/`, with no effect. The request URL is rewritten to remove `/conan` part when passing the request to the Artifactory.

Still, attempting to access `https://server.com/conan/ui` from the browser spits out an HTML with references to `/ui/...` and accessing `https://server.com/conan/artifactory` returns a redirect to `/ui` (completely ignoring any context part that was specified in `X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url`)

Is setting it up this way even possible? Do I need to change some configuration inside Artifactory to get this done? I see there is a reverse proxy configuration available through the APIs, but the documentation offers no explanation what does it really do, AFAIU, it just to generate the reverse-proxy block.

The entire NGINX location configuration, for kicks:

```
        location /conan {
                proxy_read_timeout  2400s;
                proxy_pass_header   Server;
                proxy_cookie_path   /conan/ /;
                rewrite ^/conan/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass          http://localhost:9082;
                proxy_next_upstream error timeout non_idempotent;
                proxy_next_upstream_tries    1;
                proxy_set_header    X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/conan/artifactory;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
                proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```